# Can I connect one router to another router wirelessly to be able to use the ethernet ports on the second router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

I haven’t purchased or done anything yet, but I’ve been looking into potentially moving around and upgrading some things on my home network. I’ve been looking at an MSI RadiX AXE6600 router (not entirely relevant but figured I’d mention it just in case.)

In our house, we have a splitter box in the master closet from the previous people who lived here for which our Comcast internet runs through. It contains multiple coax connections for each of the rooms in the house.

Theoretically, what we’d like to do is be able to move the Comcast modem and a router downstairs from the closet. The problem with this is there are devices that we’d want to connect via ethernet, but it’d be much harder to do due to the nature of the modem and router.

That splitter I mentioned also has CAT5E lines into each of the rooms also for the ethernet wall port. My question is this: if I were to get another router that would go upstairs, would I be able to connect that to the router downstairs to utilize its internet, while allowing the upstairs router to be used for the ethernet cable connections to go it?

Thank you so much for the help in advance.

Comment: There is no reason not to be able to connect to the second router by any available means, except that this will work at wireless speeds and be subject to interference by intervening floors, walls and electrical fields.

Comment: What you're looking for is a feature called 'client mode'

Answer (score 0):

If, by router, you mean the standaard set-up that SOHO NAT routers have, then, no, it will not work. These routers use the WiFi as access point not as client.

You may look at openwrt, an alternative firmware for routers. Openwrt should be able to support using the WiFi as client.

An alternative would be to use something like Microtik.